# Android understanding Vector

Tags: android, svg, android-vectordrawable

Thats very easy question, but Im little confused.

When we add image to app, we need different sizes of that image to put it in folders (LDPI, MDPI, HDPI, XHDPI, XXHDPI, XXXHDPI).

But now Im using android-support-library 24.2.1, which support vector graphics on pre-Lollilop devices. Is that mean I dont need LDPI, MDPI, HDPI, XHDPI, XXHDPI, XXXHDPI folders, cause I can now just import svg image as vestor (for example with Android Studio->Vector Assets) ? And will it scale properly for each screen ?

For example I import vector in `res/drawable`:

```
<vector android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0" android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <path android:fillColor="#FF000000" android:pathData="M10,20v-6h4v6h5v-8h3L12,3 2,12h3v8z"/>
</vector>
```

Will that image scale properly for each screen without creating (LDPI, MDPI, HDPI, XHDPI, XXHDPI, XXXHDPI) folders ?

Comment: *Is that mean I dont need LDPI, MDPI, HDPI, XHDPI, XXHDPI, XXXHDPI folders, cause I can now just import svg image as vestor (for example with Android Studio->Vector Assets) ? And will it scale properly for each screen ?* yes, to both.

Comment: @Blackbelt, thank you.

Comment: This is basically an image, defined mathematically, that can re-size automatically without a loss of clarity, more or less.